# Concepts of Runtime Polymorphism in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Consider the following example in VB.NET

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim myCycle As Cycle

        'Here I am making a Superclass reference to hold a subclass object
        myCycle = New SportsCycle()
        Console.WriteLine("----Cycle Details--------")

        'Using this Object I am accessing the property Wheels of the Superclass Cycle
        Console.WriteLine("Number Of Wheels: " & myCycle.Wheels)

        'Using this Object I am accessing the property getTyp of the Subclass Cycle
        Console.WriteLine("Type Of Cycle: " & myCycle.getTyp) 'Line #1(This Line is showing error)

        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

```
Public Class Cycle
    Private num_of_wheels As Integer

    Property Wheels As Integer
        Get
            Return num_of_wheels
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            num_of_wheels = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

```
Public Class SportsCycle
    Inherits Cycle

    Private type As String

    Sub New()
        type = "RAZORBIKE"
        Wheels = 2
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property getTyp As String
        Get
            Return type
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The above program is showing an error which states that "'getTyp' is not a member of
Question.Cycle in Line # 1" here 'Question' is my Project name.

Kindly clarify this concept to me. What needs to be done?

Comment: Please indent and format your code correctly, and remove all those unnecessary empty lines and comments which don’t add information, they reduce readability drastically.

Comment: You either need to declare it as the child class, or cast it to the child class as per Ric's answer.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and set `Option Strict On` to let the compiler catch this kind of error rather than waiting for it to blow up at runtime.

Comment: FYI, "type" is a keyword in VB.  Use something else.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DirectCast(myCycle, SportsCycle).getTyp
```

The reason for this is that `Cycle` does not contain this property where as `SportsCycle` does. As `SportsCycle` inherits from Cycle, you can cast to `SportsCycle` to access the property.